Какие есть способы создания трехмерной графики кроме ray casting?
Подскажите или дайте ссылку пожалуйста, никак не могу найти что-то кроме ray casting, когда ищу "Способы создания трехмерной графики" нахожу только уже упомянутый ray casting и курсы по 3d моделированию.
Ray casting мне не нравится тем, что он очень сложный для компьютера и даже самая простая 3d игра, написанная с его помощью будет очень неоптимизированной. Также в нем отсутствует возможность поворачивать камеру вниз и вверх.

Классическая растеризация же (OpenGL итп) - начните отсюда https://habr.com/ru/articles/248153/

Z-buffer. Львиная доля графических карт использует его.

Вот тут интересная подборка - https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/141523
